# It is possible to convert given C code to Assembly x86?

Tags: c, assembly

I'm working in AWD obstacle avoidance robot in assembly x86. I can find out some program which is already executed in C language but can't find executed in assembly x86. 
How do convert these C codes to Assembly x86 code?
The whole part of codes here:
http://www.mertarduino.com/arduino-obstacle-avoiding-robot-car-4wd/2018/11/22/

```
void compareDistance()   // find the longest distance
{
  if (leftDistance>rightDistance) //if left is less obstructed 
  {
    turnLeft();
  }
  else if (rightDistance>leftDistance) //if right is less obstructed
  {
    turnRight();
  }
   else //if they are equally obstructed
  {
    turnAround();
  }
}

int readPing() { // read the ultrasonic sensor distance
  delay(70);   
  unsigned int uS = sonar.ping();
  int cm = uSenter code here/US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;
  return cm;
}
```

Comment: `It is possible to convert given C code to Assembly x86?` Most likely yes, as your C compiler does exactly that.

Comment: Yes, that's what compilers are for. You could have a look at the object file, and can probably extract the assembly code from that. Or, you can just study assembler and work out how to write the assembly code yourself (better option). The code above isn't complex, so it shouldn't take too long

Comment: You need a definition for `delay(int)`, and for a `sonar` struct with a function-pointer member.  (If this is really C, not C++).  Most C implementations for x86 don't come with a delay function.  You also obviously need declarations for all the globals your code uses, because `compareDistance` doesn't take any args for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

> How do convert these C codes to Assembly x86 code?

Converting source code to assembly is basically what a compiler does, so just compile it. Most (if not all) compilers have the option of outputting the intermediate assembly code.

If you use `gcc -S main.c` you will get a file called `main.s` containing the assembly code.

Here is an example:

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_hello() {
    puts("Hello World!");
}

int main() {
    print_hello();
}

$ gcc -S hello.c 

$ cat hello.s
    .file   "hello.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello World!"
    .text
    .globl  print_hello
    .type   print_hello, @function
print_hello:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    call    puts@PLT
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   print_hello, .-print_hello
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    print_hello
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: so you mean if I use gcc compiler, then assembly code will be in there?

Comment: @DannyChoo Yes. But most (if not all) compilers can do this.

Answer (score 2):

> How do convert these C codes to Assembly x86 code?

You can use the `gcc -m32 -S main.c` command to do that, where :

- the `-S` flag indicates that the output must be assembly,
- the `-m32` flag indicates that you want to produce i386 (32-bit) output.